# How can i show a Queue in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, queue

I have a question. I have a queue and I want to show it in JLabel text, but I dont know how put the complete data from the queue in just one JLabel, I mean. I know the method JLabel.setText(), but each time I show a new data from the queue the JLabel refresh and then the data that I put before of that dissapear, and I want to show the complete Queue in a JLabel spacing the data, like this but in a JLabel...

```
 for(int i=0;i<Queue.length;i++);{
       {    System.out.print(Queue.push()+" ");}
```

and my problem is when I try to show the another data pushing the Queue, the JLabel refresh the text...

```
   for(int i=0;i<Queue.length;i++);{
       {    JLabel.setText(Queue.push()+" ");}
```

there is a method to show it correctly? thank you!.

Comment: Did you try `JLabel.setText(JLabel.getText() + Queue.push() + " ");`?

Comment: Yes i already did that, and im resolved. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect all values in a string variable and then set it.

```
String text = "";
for(int i=0;i<Queue.length;i++){
   text += Queue.push()+" ";
}
JLabel.setText(text.trim());
```

Probably it would be better to show it as HTML. So you can make the line-break

```
String text = "<html>";
for(int i=0;i<Queue.length;i++){
   text += Queue.push()+"<br>";
}
text += "</html>"
JLabel.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the text to the existing text:

```
for(int i=0;i<Queue.length;i++){
    JLabel.setText(JLabel.getText() + Queue.push()+ " ");
}
```

Or you can store the data and set it to the JLabel at the end:

```
String s = "";

for(int i=0;i<Queue.length;i++){
    s = (s + Queue.push() + " ")
}

JLabel.setText(s);
```

Hope it helps.